# Get ID from elements and put them inside an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I would like know how can i get the values of 3 div with the same class and put it inside an array.

example div

```
<div class="selected" id="1"></div>
<div class="selected" id="2"></div>
<div class="selected" id="3"></div>
```

I would like have this result `array(1,2,3)`, I saw the function each of jquery but i don't think is the right way, any idea?

Thnak you for the answer. But if i want get the id when i click a children how can i do that? example

```
   <div class="selected" id="1">
      <li>Click</li>
   </div>
    <div class="selected" id="2">
       <li>Click</li>
    </div>
    <div class="selected" id="3">
       <li>Click</li>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That looks like you want the `ID` of each div in an array, in any case:

```
var divArr = $(".selected").map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but if i want select the id of the parent when i return the element is correct do like that? return this.parent().attr('id')

Comment: @fabrizio -- No, you need a click event on the `li`, and then have this code nested in that click handler.

Answer (score 5):

You can use .map:

```
var arr = $(".selected").map(function() {
    return this.id
}).get();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i add another question. :)

Comment: @fabrizio You should not make such major edits to your question. Accept an answer here, then ask another separate question.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use as such

```
var ary = new Array();
$("div.selected").each(function(){
  ary.push(this.id);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i add another question. :)